# Mapping inside a map array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I try to make looping map inside a looping map again. But since its first time I using JS its bit hard for me to use correct tag. I want make table with first row showing the category and the second showing the item with each category they have. I already make thead and  then the next is the problem in the array.map, here what I try to make :

```
     {posts.map((category)=>  (
      <tr >
                 
    <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
       
      </td>
    
    <td   className={
          "px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left " +
          (color === "light"
            ? "bg-red-50 text-red-500 border-red-100"
            : "bg-lightBlue-800 text-lightBlue-300 border-lightBlue-700")
        }>
       {category.name}
      </td> 
      </tr> 
                   {
                   posts.filter((post)=>post.tipe_aka=== category.id).map((post) => (                   
                   <tr key={ post.id }>
                 
                     <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                     {post.id } 
                     </td>
                   
                     <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                     {post.mapel}
                     </td>
                    
                     <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                     {post.class1}
                     
             </td>
                     <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                     {post.class2}
                     
                     </td>
                     <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                     {post.class3}
                    
                    </td>
                    <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                    {post.class4}
                    
                    </td>
                    <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                    {post.class5}
                    
                    </td>
                    <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left"> 
                    {post.class6}
                    
                    </td> <td>
               <button onClick={() => deletePost(post.id)} variant="danger" size="sm">DELETE</button>
  
               </td>
                    </tr> ))}
                 
                   )
                   
              )}
```

I got error in second array.map, I dont know where I wrong maybe someone can help me thanks

My Friend told me to add html tag but its make the new table not contiune from first thead  I make...

What I want try to make is table like this :

No | Name | class 1 | class 2 |

```
Category 1
```

1  | ItemA|    5    |    2    | (has category id number 1)

2  | ItemB|    5    |    2    |

```
Category 2
```

3  | ItemC|    5    |    2    | (has categori id number 2)

Answer (score 0):

and write it like this.

```
{ posts.map((category) => {
              return(<>
                  <tr >
                      <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left"></td>
                      <td   className={
                      "px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left " +
                      (color === "light" ? "bg-red-50 text-red-500 border-red-100" : "bg-lightBlue-800 text-lightBlue-300 border-lightBlue-700")}>
                      {category.name}
                      </td> 
                  </tr></>)
              }).posts.filter((post) => post.tipe_aka === category.id).map((post) => {
                  return(<>             
                 <tr key={ post.id }>
               
                      <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                      {post.id } 
                      </td>
                  
                      <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                      {post.mapel}
                      </td>
                      
                      <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                      {post.class1}
                      </td>

                      <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                      {post.class2}
                      </td>

                      <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                      {post.class3}
                      </td>

                      <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                      {post.class4}
                      </td>

                      <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left">
                      {post.class5}
                      </td>

                      <td className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left"> 
                      {post.class6}
                      </td> 
                      
                      <td>
                          <button onClick={() => deletePost(post.id)} variant="danger" size="sm">DELETE</button>
                      </td>
           
                  </tr></>
                  )}) 
      }
```

Comment: I try it but I cant take the category.id from the post.map(category)

Comment: And its still error too cause : ×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

in the filter when I change the filter to select id category 1